# Composer require custom package caching problem

Tags: git, composer-php, gitlab

I created a package and at first I had it on an online repository @Gitlab.To use to repository I used composer.json file and added:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://remote-repo-url-path-to-package.git"
    }
]
```

That worked locally, but the moment I tried publishing it, it couldn't access it, connection time out.

I tried publishing my package on packagist, so I removed that "repositories" from my composer.json and executed `composer clearcache` and did a `composer install`. All packages are being installed correctly, but the package that's now on packagist is still trying to fetch it from my git remote repo. Weird!

So I have two issues:

1. When using Gitlab public/private repo I can't connect to fetch the composer package
2. When I than removed that link, I keeps fetching it from the repository instead of packagist.

Any ideas? :) Thanks!

Comment: Your `composer.lock` may contain old reference to VCS repo. Try to use `composer update --lock` to generate new lock and the check if `composer install` still uses old repository.

Comment: @rob006, thanks for the reply. But when doing that, it's still referring to the git repo, not to packagist. :/

Comment: What do you mean by "*referring to git repo, not to packagist*"?

Comment: @rob006 When executing composer update --lock, composer is still trying to fetch my package from my Gitlab repository. While that statement is long gone in the composer.json file. I would like that it downloads from packagist instead.

Comment: I can see the file in .composer/cache/vcs, the moment I clear cache it's gone. When I do composer install or composer update --lock it's back...

Comment: Packagist does not host your packages. Packagist keeps only package metadata, including info how to download it. On `composer install` it still needs to download package from source (GitLab in your case).